# Is this a triangulation of a cylinder?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, triangulation, simplicial-complex

[image: I am currently a beginner in Algebraic topology. I don't know whether triangulations of a thing are unique or not. So I thought to ask here whether the "triangulation" I've come up with is really a triangulation or not?]

I am currently a beginner in Algebraic topology. I don't know whether triangulations of a thing are unique or not. So I thought to ask here whether the "triangulation" I've come up with is really a triangulation or not?

I've shaded the triangles to show 2-simplexes.

P.S.- I have posted this question from the app and I'm trying to make the image horizontal.

Comment: I think it's good. Triangulations are not unique, because you can always refine the triangulation. For example, you could add a segment between $V_2$ and $V_5$, with a new vertex where the new segment meets $\overline{V_3V_4}$.

Comment: Oh great. :) That gave me some relief. @MPW